# Hibernate - Entity audit

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have one entity and I want to track all changes therefore I created new Entity for audit.
Below is my primary entity:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@Table(name = "primary")
public class PrimaryEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "primary_id")
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(
            name = "primary_attachments",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "primary_id")
    )
    private List<String> attachments;

    @CreatedDate
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date createDate;

    @LastModifiedDate
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date lastModifiedDate;
}
```

And below is my entity for audit:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@Table(name = "primary_audit")
public class PrimaryEntityAudit {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "audit_id")
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "primary_entity_id")
    private Long primaryId;

    private String name;

    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(
            name = "primary_attachments_audit",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "primary_entity_id")
    )
    private List<String> attachments = new ArrayList<>();

    @CreatedDate
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date createDate;

    public PrimaryEntityAudit(PrimaryEntity primaryEntity) {
        this.primaryId = primaryEntity.getId();
        this.attachments.addAll(primaryEntity.getAttachments());
        this.createDate = new Date();
    }
}
```

And before update primary entity I create new PrimaryEntityAudit and save this object and then update the primary entity.
And operation is successful and object PrimaryEntityAudit is saved, but attachments from PrimaryEntityAudit aren't saved.

I tried also in constructor of ProjectEntityAudit do setAttachments, but then I got an Exception: HibernateExcpetion: Found shared references to collection.

How should I map the collections of audit for saving old state of PrimaryEntity attachments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look at the following hibernate module [Envers](http://hibernate.org/orm/envers/)

It provides features for versioning and auditing

It is preferable to not reinvent the wheel except if you have technicals constraints which prevent you to use some frameworks or others.